# Bootstrap: Collapse in two columns without expansion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm creating a bootstrap collapse which the items will be divided into 2 columns but the problem now (which is the normal situation) when I expand an item it makes a gap on the other side and I want to remove that gap to make it look like the design:

[image]

In the design there's no gap but here's the actual demo collapse

[image]

```
--- row
   ---- col-xs-12 col-sm-6 (card inside)
   ---- col-xs-12 col-sm-6 (card inside)
   ---- col-xs-12 col-sm-6 (card inside)
```

It's normal when the left or the right div expands, the other div on the other side will expand too but is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Divided the main array into 2 arrays each one in a separate column then loop through it that's how I got it to work.